# RuntimeError: startApplication() failed when using squish for testing Qt applications

Tags: qt, squish

I am using `Squish 4.2.2` for testing a `GUI` developed in `Qt version 4.7` on `linux`. The `AUT` is built using statically linked Qt libraries. Since squish doesnot allow recording for statically linked Qt libraries, I am planning to manually create the test cases. However the squish test case fails with following error

```
Error Script Error Oct 31, 2012
Detail RuntimeError: startApplication() failed
```

The test case contains a single line to start the AUT. The server log shows only the following warning

```
AUT does not appear to be dynamically linked against Qt, hooking might fail.
```

Has anyone else faced a similar issue when testing Qt applications that are statically linked to Qt libraries? Kindly provide pointers for this issue.

Regards
adj

Answer (score 2):

I have run into this error before and, one of the lessons learned was that the versions of Qt that your application is using

> QtCore and QtGui

has to be compatible with the version of Qt squish was compiled with. If they are not, you get this error because squish cannot hook into the application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the following correctly setup:
1. The version of Squish must be compatible with the version of Qt used to develop the app. Usually both versions must be the SAME to be compatible.
2. When setting up Squish, point it to the correct QtCore path. 
3. Add the application in Edit -> Server Settings -> Manage AUT in the IDE.